# Printing the value of list in c#

Tags: c#, list, printing

I am trying to print the value of list. But its just printing the value of of the address.My code looks like this.

```
class Program 
{
    static void Main(string[] args) 
    {
       Node n = new Node("a", 12);
       Node n1 = new Node("b", 13);

       printNode(n);
       List<Node> a = printNode(n1);

       Console.WriteLine(a.ToString());
       Console.ReadLine();
    }


    public static List<Node> printNode(Node n)
    {
        List<Node> a = new List<Node>();
        a.Add(n);
        return a;
    }
}
```

My Node class goes like this.

```
class Node 
{
    public string value;
    public double h;
    public Node parent;

    public Node(string val, double hVal) 
    {
        value = val;
        h = hVal;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return value;
    }
}
```

How do I print [a,b] like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code currently doesn't make much sense. You're passing a `Node` to `printNode` which actually creates a *new list* and returns it.

If you simply want to print items in your list, you'll need to *iterate* that list and print it's values:

```
Node n = new Node("a", 12);
Node n1 = new Node("b", 13);

List<Node> nodes = new List<Node> { n, n1 };

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", nodes));
Console.ReadLine();
```

Here, `string.Join` will iterate your list and join each value with the `","` separator.